# get memory order compilation error when using boost 1.59 log library with clang++ 3.6

Tags: c++, boost

My demo c++ app is using boost log library, it works fine before. Recently, I upgrade my Ubuntu to 15.04 and install gcc 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.6. I compile boost 1.59 using clang tool first. Then recompile my demo c++ app, it reports compilation errors as following:

> clang++ -g -std=c++11 -I../include  -Wall -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -o
>
> ./object/main.cc.o -c ../src/main.cc In file included from
>
> ../src/main.cc:8: In file included from ../include/helper/logger.h:16:
>
> In file included from /usr/include/boost/log/sinks.hpp:25: In file
>
> included from /usr/include/boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp:42: In
>
> file included from
>
> /usr/include/boost/log/sinks/unbounded_fifo_queue.hpp:29: In file
>
> included from /usr/include/boost/log/detail/event.hpp:25: In file
>
> included from /usr/include/boost/atomic/capabilities.hpp:18: In file
>
> included from /usr/include/boost/atomic/detail/platform.hpp:22:
>
> /usr/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:35:67: error: unknown
>
> type name 'memory_order' BOOST_FORCEINLINE BOOST_CONSTEXPR int
>
> convert_memory_order_to_gcc(memory_order order) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
>
> /usr/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-atomic.hpp:37:22: error: use of
>
> undeclared identifier 'memory_order_relaxed'
>
> return (order == memory_order_relaxed ? __ATOMIC_RELAXED : (order ==
>
> memory_order_consume ? __ATOMIC_CONSUME

Comment: You should include the minimal example that triggers this. Right now it could be anything.

Comment: I tried serveral combinations. Change clang++ version, change boost version. Now, when using boost 1.55.0, both clang 3.4 and 3.6 work on my demo app. Does anybody run into this problem whe using boost 1.59?

Comment: You forgot to include that minimal example. See http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve